# Inconsistent query execution time

Tags: android, sqlite, loader

I have the same query executing over and over and sometimes it is ultra quick, other times it takes much longer. Any one know what could be causing this?

I have a Content Provider that is accessed via a loader on my activity.

It has to filter through 10,000 plus entries into a database and I had optimized it significantly to reduce query time.

Often the query runs in 0-30 ms. As I print out info every time the query executes.

But I have noticed now with more data, sometimes the query will run super quick, and other times it will take 3-5 seconds. Using the same selection/query/arguments as the fast execution.

Log is printing out the times below: And the query is exactly the same.

```
Query took 15ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 15ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 3499ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 3502ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 18ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 6ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 3618ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
Query took 3601ms to complete SELECTION: Rows: 3 :: type != ? sel args: [0]
```

I record this above log as such in the Provider

```
queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(projectionMap);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
retCursor = queryBuilder.query(mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(), null,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null, null);
//This goes with the log statement, to prevent a null pointer on selectionArgs
if (selectionArgs == null) {
    selectionArgs = new String[]{"null"};
}
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Query took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms to complete SELECTION:" +
        " Rows: " + retCursor.getCount() +
        " :: " + selection + " sel args: " + Arrays.toString(selectionArgs));
```

Edit: The table I am pulling from has half a million rows. But I put a column in with a flag to indicate if it was the last record inserted for a specific user. And indexed it. This allowed me to get a row for each users last position really quickly. A new position removes the flag on the old position and inserts the new position with the flag set. I can query the table in less than 20ms, or the ones that seem to get stuck at about 2.5 seconds or more. which seems to happen about 30-40% (est) of the time now.

Comment: Have you tried running the same query in a database tool? Does it run in constant time there?

Comment: Is there a recommended tool for testing in such a manner on a phone? Ill have to extract the query from the querybuilder I am using.

Comment: You can extract your database file and open it via https://sqlitebrowser.org/. Then you can run the query and check the execution times.

Comment: I extracted the DB file and the query using the debugger. And on my computer the query runs in 0ms, returns 3 rows. I should note the table actually has half a million rows.

Comment: Is there a difference in the statements / parameters that cause the speed to drop or they are just the same as the quick queries?

Comment: They are exactly the same every time.